# OpenMP program unexpectedly not faster with more threads

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I am a newbie to OpenMP. I write a code to calculate value of Pi by calculating the area of function `f(x) = 4/(1+x^2)`. I try to examine the efficiency with different threads. Below is my code:

```c
int main() {
    long long num_iteration = 100000000;
    double pi = 0;
    double x_margin = 1.0 / num_iteration;
    double start_time, end_time;
    int num_threads_main = 0;
    int j = NUM_THREAD;
    int a;

    for(a = 1; a <= j; a++) {
        pi = 0.0;
        omp_set_num_threads(a);
        start_time = omp_get_wtime();

        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            int i;
            int ID = omp_get_thread_num();
            double sum = 0.0;
            int num_threads_local = omp_get_num_threads();
            double x_value = 0;

            if(ID == 0)
                num_threads_main = num_threads_local;

            for (i = ID; i < num_iteration; i = i + num_threads_local) {
                x_value = x_margin * ( i + 0.5 );
                sum = sum + ( 4.0 / (1.0 + x_value * x_value));
            }

            #pragma critical
            pi = pi + sum * x_margin;
        }

        end_time = omp_get_wtime() - start_time;
        printf("pi with 1000000000 steps is %f in %f seconds with threads %d\n", pi, end_time, num_threads_main);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I got a strange result:

```
pi with 1000000000 steps is 3.141593 in 0.333257 seconds with threads 1
pi with 1000000000 steps is 3.141593 in 0.175574 seconds with threads 2
pi with 1000000000 steps is 3.141593 in 0.177884 seconds with threads 3
pi with 1000000000 steps is 3.141593 in 0.170591 seconds with threads 4
```

Why my program is not faster when there are more threads? I know there might be some overhead for OpenMP. However, I compare my code with Tim Mattson's code for OpenMP tutorial. I find quite a resemblance between the two. Below is his code:

```c
static long num_steps = 100000000;
double step;
int main ()
{
    int i,j;
    double pi, full_sum = 0.0;
    double start_time, run_time;
    double sum[MAX_THREADS];

    step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;

    for(j=1;j<=MAX_THREADS ;j++){
        omp_set_num_threads(j);
        full_sum = 0.0;
        start_time = omp_get_wtime();

        #pragma omp parallel private(i)
        {
            int id = omp_get_thread_num();
            int numthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
            double x;

            double partial_sum = 0;

            #pragma omp single
            printf(" num_threads = %d",numthreads);

            for (i=id;i< num_steps; i+=numthreads){
                x = (i+0.5)*step;
                partial_sum += + 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
            }

            #pragma omp critical
            full_sum += partial_sum;
        }

        pi = step * full_sum;
        run_time = omp_get_wtime() - start_time;
        printf("\n pi is %f in %f seconds %d threds \n ",pi,run_time,j);
    }
}
```

And this is his result:

```
 num_threads = 1
 pi is 3.141593 in 0.483153 seconds 1 threds 
  num_threads = 2
 pi is 3.141593 in 0.305407 seconds 2 threds 
  num_threads = 3
 pi is 3.141593 in 0.246802 seconds 3 threds 
  num_threads = 4
 pi is 3.141593 in 0.204905 seconds 4 threds
```

I do the experiment on my MacOS 10.15.3 with a 2.3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5. Am I missing something. Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into the differences between your code and the example you've been following.  The timings, for both, tell pretty much the same story ... there's not much advantage in adding threads after the first two.  But I wouldn't follow that example - I'd replace the use of a `critical` section for reducing values across threads by a `reduction`, something like the code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323418/openmp-vs-gcc-compiler-optimizations

Comment: What compiler do you use and with what options do you compile your code?

Comment: Please read up on omp for... Your code is not really OpenMP, rather it's naked threads hidden behind an OpenMP veneer. So you're doing lots of work that you don't need to do, since OpenMP can do it for you. (Once you've done that also look at reductons...)